# React native "network error" due to HTTP server

Tags: react-native, http, networking, axios

Okay, I didn't receive a response from the HTTP server in React Native during the release time of the APK but it is perfectly work during development /debug time. In other words, React Native prohibited me from using the HTTP server.

```
// Axios GET request to get date information
axios.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
  .then((response: AxiosResponse<DateData>) => {
    setDateData(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error fetching date data:', error);
  });
```

how to rectified that problem

Comment: for this problem i got solution  first Modify android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

Open the network_security_config.xml file in the res/xml directory of your Android project.if you dont have xml folder in that place then create.

Comment: then add this into that <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: after that please mention this <application
    ...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
    ...
</application> into your androidmenifest.xml

Comment: clean the gradlew -: ./gradlew clean and rebuild your build apk :-npx react-native build-android --mode=release. and for apk:-npm run android -- --mode="release"

Answer (score 0):

for this problem a solution is first to Modify `android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml:` Open the `network_security_config.xml` file in the res/xml directory of your Android project. if you don't have xml folder in that place then create.

then add this to that

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <network-security-config> <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"> <trust-anchors> <certificates src="system" /> </trust-anchors> </base-config> </network-security-config>
```

after that please mention this `<application ... android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"> ... </application> into your androidmenifest.xml`
clean the gradlew -: `./gradlew clean and rebuild your build apk :-npx react-native build-android --mode=release.` and for apk:-`npm run android -- --mode="release"`